# Keep namespacing of a controller when including a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to keep the namespace of a class when including a module. 
Lets say I have these Models:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
end
class A::Shop < ::Shop
end
class B::Shop < ::Shop
end
```

And this controller:

```
module A
  class ShopController < AuthenticatedController
    include Basic::Features
    def test
      p Shop.new #YES! its a A::Shop 
    end
  end
end
```

And this Module:

```
module Basic
  module Features
    def test
      p Shop.new  #Shop (abstract)
    end
  end
end
```

In the above example, the namespace is overwritten when including the module. 
As I want to use the `Basic::Features` module at multiple places in my codebase, I would like to automatically switch between `A::Shop` and `B::Shop` when including it in the controller.

Anybody any idea if this is possible, and how.

Comment: Long shot, but you could try `self.class::Shop.new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
module Basic
  module Features
    def test
      p Object.const_get('::' + self.class.to_s.split('::').first + '::Shop')
    end
  end
end
```

It will not work if you have deeper namespaces, e.g. `A::B::Shop`, but it could be made to work. Also in rails you could use `deconstantize` instead of `split`.

I think the reason you code does not work is because it is looking in `A::ShopController` namespace and since not found it then tries the root namespace, `::`, and finds `Shop`.

Comment: Hi Kris, Yes this could be a sound solution! Thanxs!